# Creating threads in python-multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I have the following threads structure:

```
               (1)
            /   |   \
          (2)  (3)  (4)
           |    |    |
          (5)  (6)  (7)
           |    |    |
          (8)  (9)  (10)
           |    |    |
          (11) (12) (13)
            \  /     |
            (14)     |
              \     /
                (15)
```

As you can see, the first function starts three threads, and then each starts a new one. The 14th node is the join of the 11th and 12th; the 15th is the join of the 13th and 14th.
I implemented the first two levels (nodes 1, 2, 3, 4) as follows:

```
self.first()
    list = ['a','b','c']
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        results = executor.map(self.do_this, list)
        for result in results:
            print(result)
```

But have no idea where to go from here.

Comment: Sounds like you might want to consider a task-based structure instead of thinking in threads, where subsequent tasks wait for their predecessors to complete first.

Comment: @AKX if you could please give me more details? :) I do not seem to find online anything helpful about task-based structures

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of a runner for a graph like yours.

The idea is that you define a function that runs each task (`do_task` here), and build a graph of the (immediate) dependencies each task requires. The example `task_deps` below mirrors your graph from above.

The `run_graph` function will then call `do_task`  with each task ID; the function is supposed to do whatever it needs to compute your result (it can read the `results` of any previous computation if it needs to).

The `run_graph` function will eventually return a dict of `{task_id: result}`.

The code below outputs

```
Scheduling {1}
Scheduling {2, 3, 4}
Scheduling {5, 6, 7}
Scheduling {8, 9, 10}
Scheduling {11, 12, 13}
Scheduling {14}
Scheduling {15}
```

which, as supposed, corresponds exactly to the structure of your graph from top to bottom,
and

```
{1: 'Task 1 completed with result 42',
 2: 'Task 2 completed with result 84',
 3: 'Task 3 completed with result 126',
 4: 'Task 4 completed with result 168',
 5: 'Task 5 completed with result 210',
 6: 'Task 6 completed with result 252',
 7: 'Task 7 completed with result 294',
 8: 'Task 8 completed with result 336',
 9: 'Task 9 completed with result 378',
 10: 'Task 10 completed with result 420',
 11: 'Task 11 completed with result 462',
 12: 'Task 12 completed with result 504',
 13: 'Task 13 completed with result 546',
 14: 'Task 14 completed with result 588',
 15: 'Task 15 completed with result 630'}
```

---

```
import concurrent.futures


def do_task(task_id, results, dependencies):
    # sanity check - this function could use `dependencies` and `results` too
    assert all(dep in results for dep in dependencies)
    return f"Task {task_id} completed with result {task_id * 42}"


def run_graph(task_dependencies, runner):
    # Dict for results for each task.
    results = {}
    # Set of tasks yet to be completed.
    todo = set(task_dependencies)

    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        # While there are items in the to-do set...
        while todo:
            # ... figure out what we can immediately execute by
            # comparing the dependency set to the result keys we already have
            # (i.e. the complement of the to-do set)
            next_tasks = {
                task_id
                for (task_id, deps) in task_dependencies.items()
                if task_id in todo and set(deps) <= set(results)
            }
            # If there are no next tasks we could schedule, it means the dependency
            # graph is incorrect (or at the very least incompleteable).
            if not next_tasks:
                raise RuntimeError(
                    f"Unable to schedule tasks, bad dependencies? Todo: {todo}"
                )

            print("Scheduling", next_tasks)
            # Submit tasks for execution in parallel. `futures` will be a list of
            # 2-tuples (task_id, future).
            futures = [
                (
                    task_id,
                    executor.submit(
                        runner, task_id, results, task_dependencies[task_id]
                    ),
                )
                for task_id in next_tasks
            ]

            # Loop over the futures, waiting for their results; when a future
            # finishes, save the result value and remove that task from the
            # to-do set.
            for (task_id, future) in futures:
                results[task_id] = future.result()
                todo.remove(task_id)
    # Once the while loop finishes, we have our results.
    return results


if __name__ == "__main__":
    task_deps = {
        1: (),
        2: (1,),
        3: (1,),
        4: (1,),
        5: (2,),
        6: (3,),
        7: (4,),
        8: (5,),
        9: (6,),
        10: (7,),
        11: (8,),
        12: (9,),
        13: (10,),
        14: (11, 12),
        15: (14, 13),
    }

    result = run_graph(task_deps, do_task)
    print(result)
```